# Xcode Error: 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

After running `pod update` on my project, I am now getting the errors:

> 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

and (I imagine associated):

> Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

I have tried deintegrating and installing pods multiple times, creating new workspaces (and making sure I am in workspace rather than project). I am not all that experienced in programming (yet!), but my podfile contains `use_frameworks!` in case that's of any help?

I have also noticed that when I build my app I get a warning about not being able to find the pod.[AppName].xcconfig file, although the file isn't highlighted in red and appears to still be where it says?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764165/could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase)

Comment: You got [multiple duplicates to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%27FirebaseCore%2FFirebaseCore.h%27+file+not+found+is%3Aq): what's different in your question? Also, please specify your CocoaPods version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase': I have Xcode version 9.4.1 & Cocoapods 1.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025067/could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase-i-have-xcode-version-9-4-1-coco)

Comment: You can do yourself alot of benefit by learning how to examine the build command line (by expanding the lines of the Build tab) and checking what include directives are being used.  You can then examine the filesystem to see if these folder exist or not.

Comment: @trojanfoe oh, so you don't vote to close as duplicate? ;)

Comment: @Cœur Not sure it is a duplicate.  File not found errors can be caused by many different problems.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue, i simply reinstall the pod file through command prompt like
pod install
so then my project start working.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Hi, i was facing this issue . But i have this fixed error now. Go to Pod file and add "pod 'Firebase/Core', :modular_header => true and "pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :modular_header => true

[image]

Comment: not singular modular_header. prural modular_headers

Comment: Tajinder singh fix it

Comment: What you want to say @shinriyo?, sorry i didn't understand.
i added :modular_header => true and its working

Comment: I mean your screenshot is "modular_headers", plural. 
but, your text is "modular_header", singular.

Comment: You're welcome. spelling is important in the programming world.
We don't have plural/singular form in Japanese. So, I can understand it is troublesome.